# Are identity pools in AWS Cognito used only for app management?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-identitypools

I have read about AWS cognito and I understand that User pools is an identity provider that is used to authenticate users to your mobile app, website and manage users. Then there is Identity pools that are used to authorize users to give access to your aws resources such as IAM, S3 and etc.

So my question is: Are identity pools used for the app management like by devs, dev-ops or anyone who needs to manage/update the apps? Is that the work of identity pools?

Answer (score 1):

Identity pools are not (necessarily) used for app management. I can tell you about how my team used them at my last job. (There are probably other use cases, but I suspect ours was a fairly common one.)

We were building an app where users needed to upload and download files that we would store in S3. For various reasons, we wanted the client to interact directly with S3 for file transfer (as opposed to pushing files through an API layer that we would have to maintain). Identity Pools were made for exactly this sort of scenario. Basically they allow a client to exchange an identity token for a set of temporary IAM credentials (access_key_id + secret_access_key + session_token). The temporary IAM credentials are what the client needs to interact with an AWS SDK or create a signed HTTP request for one of AWS's native services.

The identity token that gets exchanged for credentials could be provided by Cognito User Pools, but it could also come from a different identity provider. We used Auth0 as an identity provider, for example. But we still wanted our client to interact directly with S3 and for that we needed Cognito Identity Pools.

One really cool feature of Identity Pools that we took advantage of was what Cognito calls *Principal Tag Mapping*, which is the ability to map claims (attributes) in the Auth0-provided identity token to *session tags*, which are kind of like environment variables that are attached to the temporary credentials' session. You can then write IAM policies that incorporate session tags to do attribute-based access control. We wrote S3 bucket policies that provided fine-grained access control where each user was only allowed to read and write to a prefix that contained their own user id.

I have to say that the distinction between User Pools and Identity Pools in Cognito confuses everyone and AWS's documentation isn't always as helpful as it could be on this point.